# Basic Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ right now and I have a probably very basic question.

If I have the following in a .h file:

```
class Top{
    Top();
    virtual ~Top() = 0;
}

class Bottom: public Top{
    public:
       Bottom(char core);
       virtual ~Bottom();
    public:
       char getCore() const;
    private:
       char core;  
}
```

Would the implementation of Bottom look like the following?

```
Top::Top(): Top() {}

//Bottom
Bottom::Top(char core){
    core = core;
}

char Bottom::getCore(){
    return core;
}
```

Or

```
Top::Top(): Top() {}

//Bottom
Bottom::Bottom(char core){
    core = core;
}

char Bottom::getCore(){
    return core;
}
```

Comment: What is `virtual ~Operator();`?

Comment: It is my understanding that a method following a tilde is a deconstructor.

Comment: The bottom version of Bottom is the right one

Comment: @FatalProphet It also needs to be named after the class : ~Bottom();

Comment: You are shadowing member property when you declare a method with the same name as it... I am not sure what do you expect by writing `Bottom::Bottom(char core){core = core;}`. Also if you have a question where you give two options, why won't you try it yourself. It's not like an hour of coding that would go in vain.

Comment: The Top constructors are bad: Delegate construction of top using the standard constructor to the standard constructor? That's a loop.

Comment: Constructors are not inherited by the subclass.

Comment: Also, you want `Top` to be pure virtual? Ok, but you still need to implement `~Top` if you want any concrete derived classes.

Comment: @Deduplicator: No, there's no implementation of `Top::~Top()` because it's pure virtual. What is required is that every subclass must have a destructor, e.g. `Bottom::~Bottom()` must exist.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: If there is no implementation (even pure virtual functions **can** have an implementation) for a base-class destructor, there's no way to define the derived-class destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

```
class Top{
    Top();
    virtual ~Top() = 0;
}
```

`class` access control defaults to `private`. This means that this class has a private constructor and thus cannot be constructed, nor can subclasses be constructed. A fixed version would probably look like:

```
class Top {
protected:
    Top();
    virtual ~Top() = 0;
}
```

The `virtual` destructor means you can't create a `Top`, but you could still create a subclass.

And as @Deduplicator pointed out, you still need a definition for `Top::~Top()` because subclasses' destructors will call it:

```
Top::~Top() {}
```

The declaration of `class Bottom` looks fine, though you don't need to repeat `public:`.

And one minor problem with both class definitions: you forgot the semicolon after the closing brace.

As for the implementation:

```
Top::Top(): Top() {}
```

The third `Top` is incorrect. That syntax is used to pass things to a superclass's constructor, or delegate to another constructor (of which you have none). `Top` is not its own superclass. The correct code is simply:

```
Top::Top() {}
```

Moving on...

```
Bottom::Bottom(char core){
    core = core;
}
```

This has a problem because the parameter `core` hides the class member `core`. They need to be different names (though there is no requirement that the parameter name in a class declaration match the one in the method definition). I usually fix this by adding a trailing underscore to the parameter name:

```
Bottom::Bottom(char core_) {
    core = core_;
}
```

Finally:

```
char Bottom::getCore(){
    return core;
}
```

This is wrong because you declared it as a `const` method but this definition is not `const`. Fixed:

```
char Bottom::getCore() const {
    return core;
}
```

BTW, you can have `const` and non-`const` versions of a method. Which one runs depends on if `this` is `const` or not.

One last thing: you forgot to define `Bottom::~Bottom()`. Add this:

```
Bottom::~Bottom() {
}
```

I've got a fixed version of this code, plus some token test code, [posted online.](http://codepad.org/7tpN0hsg)

Comment: The third Top is incorrect: **Delegating** or superclass.

Comment: core = core: One could use `this`instead.

Comment: Top::~Top() is missing too.

Comment: Was fixing all that, and writing a test version to catch anything else, while you were commenting. :P

Comment: As for using `this`: Technically yes, but it should be discouraged because humans reading the code might think `core` refers to the class member if they forgot that it's a parameter.

Comment: That happens with unchecked concurrency... And yes, it should be pointed out as possible, though you are right and a strong cautionary note is in order there too.

Comment: At least I don't have to merge.

Comment: in `Bottom`'s constructor, it's more idiomatic to use an initializer list